# JavaScript - check if string of html has only empty tags or &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm mapping an event calendar and one of the json nodes is an artist bio.

For the bio node I'll get something like this and append it to the bio div.

```
<p>John Doe was born in Nantucket..</p>
<p>Yada yada</p>
```

However, sometimes I get something like this and I want to set it to null so it doesn't print:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

How can I check the string for empty tags and / or `&nbsp;` specifically, i.e.

```
if(event.bio //has only empty tags || only white space || '&nbsp;') { 
     bio = null; 
}
```

Comment: This sort of thing sounds perfect for a regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
const aux = document.createElement('div');
aux.innerHTML = yourString; //parses the html
const trimmedContent = aux.innerText.trim(); //get only the text and remove white space at the beginning and end
```

Then you can check if `trimmedContent == ''` to know if it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let content = "<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp; </p><p>&nbsp; </p>"

content = content = content.replace(/(<\/?[^>]+(>|$)|&nbsp;|\s)/g, ""); 

if (content === "") bio = null
```

For clarity,

```
 content = content = content.replace(/(<\/?[^>]+(>|$)|&nbsp;|\s)/g, "");
```

is a concise form of:

```
content = content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""); //&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
content = content.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ""); //a space char
content = content.replace(/\s/g, ""); //empty string
```